# Simplest C makefile using implicit rules

Tags: c, makefile

I know it is not optimal at all to rely on `make`'s implicit rules but
my goal is to understand why they are not working in this case.
I want to write the simplest makefile one can write for a C project
without having to specify the sources.

I have tried to run `make -d` but the ouput is too big and verbose to
really be helpful.

I have written makefiles for some time and I believe I am familiar with how it
works. I am pretty sure I have managed to get implicit rules to work for me both
compiling and linking in the past but apparently I am forgetting something.

Here's what I have tried :

```
SRCS    =   $(wildcard  *.c)
OBJS    =   ${SRCS:.c=.o}

NAME=exe

${NAME}:    ${OBJS} 

clean:
            rm -rf *.o

fclean:     clean
            rm -rf ${NAME}

re:         fclean ${NAME}

.PHONY: clean fclean re
```

It almost works but it doesn't link.

I am using gnu make version 4.3

Comment: Why isn't it optimal to rely on implicit rules?  On the contrary I think any makefile that DOESN'T use implicit rules wherever possible is sub-optimal because it doesn't adhere to the DRY principle.

Comment: @MadScientist Well, there are many principles in programming and none
is absolute. I could argue that "explicit is better than implicit".
My opinion on the matter simply comes from the fact that when I asked
that question on IRC, I was told : "Don't use them".
Also it is recommended in many `make` tutorials to use the no-builtin-variable option.
The general opinion seems to be that they are a bit opaque and not
easy to debug.

Comment: Well, if explicit is better than implicit why have any functions at all? Your entire program could be written out as one long function with no other calls, because writing the code explicitly is better than performing some action implicitly by calling a function, right?  My experience is that knowledge obtained from random make tutorials on the internet is typically worth less than you paid for them.  They are rife with errors and misunderstandings.  I recommend reading the GNU make manual.  And, ditto for random advice on IRC.  Of course, you have no reason to believe me either I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Makefile doesn't execute the link step because there is only a very simple implicit rule for linking. From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html):

> **Linking a single object file**
>
> *n* is made automatically from *n.o* by running the C compiler to link the program. The precise recipe used is `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`.
>
> This rule does the right thing for a simple program with only one source file. It will also do the right thing if there are multiple object files (presumably coming from various other source files), one of which has a name matching that of the executable file. Thus,
>
> ```
> x: y.o z.o
> ```

In other words, for your Makefile to work, `NAME` needs to match the basename of one of your object files.

For example, if I have your `Makefile` and a single source file named `hello.c`, I can run:

```
make NAME=hello
```

And see the result:

```
cc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
cc   hello.o   -o hello
```

Comment: OoopOooops, I should not have skipped the end of that documentation
page. Hopefully that helps someone in the future. Thanks.